# Error en codigo de flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

necesito una ayuda, soy nuevo en flutter y me a gustado mucho la plataforma pero e tenido muchos problemas con el aprendizaje debido a que siempre encuentro ejemplos de codigos que ya estan deprecated, estoy tratando de hacer una app bajo modelo Bloc, en los ejemplos que sigo dentro de bloc_user.dart estoy agregando  la funcion para poder conectar a firebase.  como tengo dos clases en donde el objeto usuario se llama igual es agregado una de las dos como modelo: user.dart as userModel, pero siempre me da error de usuario. a que se debe el problema?

[image: Como pueden ver marca en rojo user]

Aqui pongo el codigo:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:generic_bloc_provider/generic_bloc_provider.dart';
import '../../Core/repository/cloud_firestore_repository.dart';
import '../../Core/repository/auth_repository.dart';
import '../../Core/model/user.dart'as userModel;

class UserBloc implements Bloc{
  final _auth_repository = AuthRepository();

  //Flujo de datos - Streams
  //Stream - Firebase
  Stream <User?> streamFirebase = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
  Stream<User?> get authStatus => streamFirebase;

  //Casos de uso
  //1.Iniciar sesion con Google
  Future<UserCredential> signIn(){
    return _auth_repository.signInFirebase();
  }
//2. Registrar usuario en base de datos
  final _cloudFirestoreRepository = CloudFirestoreRepository();
  void updateUserData(userModel.User user) => _cloudFirestoreRepository.updateUserDataFirestore(user);

  signOut(){
    _auth_repository.signOut();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){

  }

}
```

agrege la imagen para que se vea lo que me marca de error el editor

Comment: Agrega el código como texto, no imágenes.

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion a mi problema, por si alguien mas le pasa. Las rutas de mis importaciones estaban dando erro unas estaban relativas y otras absolutas, las deje absolutas y el error se fue.